# No Grub after installing windows 10

Tags: 14.04

I recently installed windows 10 and then installed ubuntu 14.04. But there is no grub option upon restart and so the system reboots to windows automatically.I checked the Boot Option and it just shows `OS Boot Manager` and does not show `ubuntu`. Is there some way I can fix this?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? May be best to see details: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @oldfred http://paste.ubuntu.com/13076100/

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you still have SecureBoot on, and this causes Windows 10 to boot up regardless of the OS installed. You'll need to disable it within your BIOS, and swap the bootloader. In Windows 10, hold the SHIFT key while tapping or clicking on Restart, available from any Power icon.[image]

Select Troubleshoot and UEFI Firmware Settings.
[image]

Navigate your way to "Boot" (since BIOS is different for each computer).
Swap the "Windows-Boot(anything related to Windows) with the Ubuntu one(can't remember the name. So your boot should look something like this.

`1. Ubuntu (something with Ubuntu)`

`2. Windows Boot Loader`

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that you have the windows bootloader if this is so add your ubuntu using easy BCD (https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

Else use you live cd and try [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for reinstalling GRUB

Comment: Grub is already installed. I checked it again using boot repair. It is just not showing upon restart.